# How to avoid a large number to be in scientific notation in verilog

Tags: verilog

In a case statement case(s), the nvalue of s is increased by the power of 2.

```
input[127:0] s 
output[127:0] y

case(s)
  128'b1: y=a1; 
  128'b2: y=a2;
...
```

When it goes to 2^64, the number is so big and it will be represented automatically by scientific notation, eg.

```
128'b1.84467e19: y=a64
```

This will give me a syntax error, is there a way to avoid this?

I don't want to define it as real, since I want to synthesise this code.

Comment: This sounds like an editor problem or a code-generator problem, not a Verilog problem. So far as I know, nothing in Verilog prevents you writing out all the bits of a constant like `128'b0000_0000_0000_..._0000_0000_0000`.

Comment: Cross posted on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17793683/97073).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do use python to generate this power of 2 function. So you mean I should define in Python to not express this number is scientific notation?

Comment: Thank you very much!!!I googled the way to suppress that in Python. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't that it is in scientific notation. It's that you used digits other than 0 and 1 with a 'b base specifier. You need 'd or 'h for decimal or hex. I would't expect 128'b2 to work either.

Comment: Oops, I am sorry, I mistyped the 128'b , in the original code it is 128'd, really sorry...and when the number is not in scientific notation, it can be synthesized and simulated...do you have any idea how to do this? Thank you very much.